# ERROR: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have been trying to access the information about my Facebook PAGE using `cURL`. I passed the url me/accounts in Graph Explorer which shows some data as follows:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "tokenString", 
      "category": "Small business", 
      "name": "myPageName", 
      "id": "xxx", 
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER", 
        "EDIT_PROFILE", 
        "CREATE_CONTENT", 
        "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
        "CREATE_ADS", 
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTM4NzYwMjM5NDg5NTUzOQ==", 
      "after": "MTM4NzYwMjM5NDg5NTUzOQ=="
    }
  }
}
```

But when I tried to get the same thing in cURL and run through terminal it gives me an error "**Unsupported GET request**"

> **Code:**

```
<?php
  $url='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/accounts';
  $ch=curl_init();
  CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $json=json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  var_dump($json);
?>
```

> **Error:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(114) "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
    ["type"]=>
    string(20) "GraphMethodException"
    ["code"]=>
    int(100)
  }
}
```

Page permission: `manage_pages,publish_pages`

I checked for age restrictions: It is open to all.

Then where am I going wrong ? Thanks for any help

Comment: Is curl enabled on your server?

Comment: yes. I can run other scripts successfully.

Comment: I don’t see you passing any access token with your cURL call …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Graph Explorer, an Access Token is automatically added to each request. If you do the same request via cUrl without explicitly adding an Access Token as URL parameter, then it will fail.

You need to add the `access_token` parameter to your call, and an Access Token with `manage_pages` permission (replace `{access_token}`).

```
<?php
  $url='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/accounts?access_token={access_token}';
  $ch=curl_init();
  CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $json=json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  var_dump($json);
?>
```

Comment: One more question I have. Here, this access_token will be called as 'user_access_token' or 'page_access_token' ?

Comment: It needs to be an User Access Token. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens about the differences.